# Problemas com a estrutura de repetição While

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando criar um programa baseado na estrutura de repetição `while`, mas o laço não finaliza.

```
sexo = str(input('Digite seu sexo:'))
if sexo != 'M' or sexo != 'F':
    while sexo != 'M' or sexo != 'F':
        sex = str(input('Digite seu sexo:'))
else:
```

Também tentei criar uma função def para o `input` mas não consegui, se for possível também use essa função na explicação.

Comment: Se `sexo` vale `'M'`, ele é diferente de `'F'`, então a condição é verdadeira. Se vale `'F'`, ele é diferente de `'M'`, então a condição é verdadeira; nunca parando o loop. Tente mudar de `or` para `and`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos simplificar (pena que Python não tenha um `do` ou `repeat`:

```
while True:
    sex = input('Digite seu sexo:')
    if sex == 'M' or sex == 'F':
        break
```

Quer continuar fazendo daquela forma?

```
sex = input('Digite seu sexo:')
while sex != 'M' and sex != 'F':
    sex = input('Digite seu sexo:')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/RepeatWhile.py).

Notou a diferença?

É o `or` que virou `and`. Quando você vai inverter uma condição tem que inverter todos os operadores. O contrário de `==` é `!=`, o contrário de `or` é `and`.

Obviamente que se quiser colocar o `if` de novo, pode, desde que a condição seja corrigida. Achei que ele não tem utilidade aí, mas pode ter outro trecho de código que pode exigi-lo, mas eu ainda faria de outra forma.

A condição que você está querendo fazer é que algo saia da repetição quando for digitado o que deseja, certo? Então terminará o laço quando digitar `M` **OU** `F`, está lá no `if` do meu primeiro código.

Quando você quer dizer uma condição que deve indicar que o laço deve continuar repetindo, que é o caso do `while` (ela continua quando é verdadeiro), você tem que fazer o inverso da condição que determina a saída. Então você quer que ele continue sempre que for digitado algo diferente de `M` **E** diferente de `F`.

Se usar um **OU** aí, `M` é diferente de `F`, e não pode ter digitado os dois caracteres aos mesmo tempo, então a condição sempre seria verdadeira porque ou o primeiro seria diferente ou o segundo seria diferente, não tem como ambos serem diferentes.

Comment: Acho que `str(input(...))` também seja redundante, já que `input` sempre retorna uma *string*

Comment: Força do hábito, já vou corrigir.

Comment: Pode exemplificar como funciona esse While True?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss nem olhei pras partes que ñ importavam, obrigado :) Tinha mais erro :D

Comment: @LucasSouza este é um exemplo.

Comment: @Maniero sobre a função def eu percebi que tornaria o código até maior, mas mesmo assim poderia dar um exemplo de como ficaria no caso do input, retornando a função depois do while?

Comment: Não sei de que função você está falando, não sei onde tem um `def`, "exemplo de como ficaria" o que? Me parece que você tem outra pergunta.

Comment: @Maniero fiz a pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257173/92132