# Uso da função def

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Gostaria de criar uma função `def` para o primeiro `input` e depois retorná-lo na terceira linha.

Exemplo:

```
def se():
    sex = input('Digite seu sexo:')

while sex != 'M' and sex != 'F':
    #não sei como se retorna esta parte: sex = input('Digite seu sexo:')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def` é uma palavra-chave de construção da linguagem, ela não é uma função, ela serve justamente para declarar e definir uma função.

O seu código, pela indentação postada, não faz o que deseja, Python é sensitivo à indentação. Então

```
def se():
    sex = input('Digite seu sexo:')
```

é a função e

```
while sex != 'M' and sex != 'F':
```

é um código solto.

O que provavelmente deseja é isto:

```
def getSex():
    while True:
        sex = input('Digite seu sexo:')
        if sex == 'M' or sex == 'F':
            return sex

print(getSex())
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/p2M1Pz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/avcjvqmn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ValidationSex.py)

O `return` encerra uma função e ele pode, opcionalmente, entregar um resultado para quem chamou, como toda função matemática faz (programação não inventa nada, é tudo matemática, quase tudo que se ensina na escola).

Claro que tem muito o que melhorar nisto, mas o foco da pergunta é este.

Answer (score 0):

A palavra reservada def inicia a definição de uma função. Ela deve ser seguida do nome da função e da lista de parâmetros formais entre parênteses. Os comandos que formam o corpo da função começam na linha seguinte e devem ser indentados.

Por exemplo:

```
def fib2(n):  
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
       result.append(a)    
       a, b = b, a+b
 return result
```

A instrução return finaliza a execução e retorna um valor da função. return sem qualquer expressão como argumento retorna None. Atingir o final da função também retorna None.

Existe uma documentação muito boa sobre funções no site oficial da linguagem Python vou deixar o link aqui em baixo:

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions